# How to retrieve certificate thumbprint of the local Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

We have an application consisting of microservices and also using various Azure resources, like CosmosDB, Redis, EventHub.

So we have written a Powershell script, which retrieves various secrets from Azure resource group: CosmosDB connection strings and same for Redis and Eventhub. Also the SF certificate thumbprint is read from the Key Vault in the resource group. The secrets are then stored in a Json file outside the git work area.

Then in the Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 we read the Json file and use the secrets to replace the placeholders:

```
$jsonFile = "$rootDir\secrets.json"
$secretsHashtable = @{}
(Get-Content $jsonFile| ConvertFrom-Json).psobject.properties | Foreach { $secretsHashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

$ApplicationPackagePath = Resolve-Path $ApplicationPackagePath

$publishProfile = Read-PublishProfile $PublishProfileFile

if ($PublishProfileFile.EndsWith("Local.1Node.xml"))
{
    $secretsHashtable['Cluster-Host-Name'] = 'localhost'
    # TODO store the local SF certificate thumbprint in $secretsHashtable['SSL-Certificate-Find-Value']
    $publishProfile.CopyPackageParameters.CompressPackage = $true
    $OutFile = "$LocalFolder\..\ApplicationParameters\Local.1Node.xml"
}
else
{
    $OutFile = "$LocalFolder\..\ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml"
}

# Replace $( ... ) in Cloud.Template.xml by the values from the hashtable
$TemplateFile = "$LocalFolder\..\ApplicationParameters\Template.xml"
$TemplateStr  = Get-Content $TemplateFile -Raw
$ReplacedStr  = [regex]::Replace($TemplateStr, '\$\(([\w-]+)\)', {
    param($match)
    $key = $match.Groups[1].Value
    $value = $secretsHashtable[$key]
    if ($value -ne $null)
    {
        return $value
    }
    else
    {
        throw "$key not found in $jsonFile"
    }
})

Set-Content -Path $OutFile -Value $ReplacedStr
```

This works for the remote publishing and debugging (from Visual Studio 2017) using Cloud.xml.

However it fails for Local.1Node.xml, because our application checks the certificate thumbprint through the entry in ServiceManifest.xml

```
<Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpoint" 
    Type="Input" Port="9950" CertificateRef="MY_CERT" />
```

And thus publishing the SF app locally fails with:

[image: event viewer log]

My question is: how to retrieve the certificate thumbprint of the local Service Fabric SDK installation?

If I could do that, I would put it in the above script (please see the "TODO" comment)

Comment: I want to help but I'm a little bit confused. If you are using Azure SF you should have your certificates in KeyVault, correct? If this is a case, your application or user should have access to KeyVault for retrieving certificates, before running deployments.

Local Service Fabric doesn't require you to have certificates, so you can run test deployments for testing, etc.

Comment: Hi Oleh, I think for the local SF there are some certificates used. And since they are not embedded in my Cloud.xml, our app fails. I have yet to find the spot in the source code where it (the thumbprint verification) happens, I was shown it some time ago by a colleague. The remote execution is ok, the cert is in KV and installed at the remote SF, as you have written.

Comment: I think that I use the standard deployment tools, but I had to edit the Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 (which is delivered with VS2017, Azure Tools), to embed the CosmosDB, Redis, Eventhub connection strings in Cloud.xml and Local.1Node.xml

Comment: Can you please share error message that you have?

Comment: I'd installed a fresh copy of SF on my local machine few days ago and I have no problems for local deployments. This is why I'm confused about it. Then you are connecting to local cluster it asking for a certificate? Through web or SF explorer?

Comment: I don’t think this is a good idea to set application parameters in sf deployments file. You should use separate file for this, like Setting.xml

Comment: I have found the spot where the app (consisting of 3 stateless microservices) check the cert: in ServiceManifest.xml `<Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="9950" CertificateRef="MY_CERT" />`

Comment: The error I see in the Windows Event Viewer when launching at localhost SF: `Failed to configure port certificate for port: 9950, certificatefindvalue 13xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx15, error 0x80070520`

Comment: How about using HTTP for endpoint? If no, then probably you would need cert thumbprint, try to install endpoint certificate locally on SF machine.
Please take a look on this article https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem with:

```
Write-Host "Retrieving thumbprint for local SF certificate... " -NoNewline
$localCert = Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where { $_.Subject -eq 'CN=AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient'}
Write-Host "ok"
```

Now I am able to debug in Visual Studio both locally and remotely (at the SF deployed in Azure).